# How do I remove the outline from a button when clicked if outline is not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the yellow outline with `outline: none` but it's not working. I tried to put the property on every action, but with no success. Any ideas on why is not working?

```css
.save {
    background-color:  #99aab5;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Comic Neue', cursive;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 125px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
    box-shadow: 1px 4px 2px #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 13rem;
    right: 2.7rem;
    outline: none;
 }
.save:hover {
     color: azure;
 }
.save:active {
   transform: translateY(4px);
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px;
   outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
```

Comment: I don't see the yellow outline when clicking the button, what browser are you using? I am on Chrome latest version

Comment: I'm using electron

Answer (score 3):

It might not be an outline. In my experience, it can be a border or even a box shadow.

Try using this:

```css
button{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

if this does not work then you have to check the Chrome dev console in the element tab to see which style is causing the yellow outline.